# How to Exit a Dropdown Surrounded by Un-Interactable Transparent Overlay in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I am writing a test with selenium specflow where I must open a dropdown and select a category. The way that the devs have it set up, the only way to close the dropdown after selection is by clicking elsewhere on the page. Manually, this is doable.

This becomes an issue when interacting with the webpage with selenium, as there is a transparent overlay surrounding the dropdown once it is opened. I have tried to click the overlay, but I get ElementNonInteractable Exception. Trying to click other elements on the page (other than those in the dropdown) returns an ObjectNotClickable Exception (since the overlay is on top).

I have tried using SendKeys.Return on the overlay as well. Is there any other way I can exit out of this overlay?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by following 3 types:

**1.The element is not visible to click.**

Use **Actions** or **JavascriptExecutor** for making it to click.

By Actions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

By JavascriptExecutor:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); // if the element is on top.

jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)"); // if the element is on bottom.
```

or

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Webelement);
```

hen click on the element.

**2.The page is getting refreshed before it is clicking the element.**

For this, make the page to wait for few seconds.

**3. The element is clickable but there is a spinner/overlay on top of it**

The below code will wait until the overlay disppears

```
By loadingImage = By.id("loading image ID");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loadingImage));
```

Then click on the element.

Comment: @Meher, Please accept the answer  if this has resolved your problem